# SQL comparisons

Tags: sql

```
case when 3<myInputValue<6then 
          --do something
     when 6<myInputValue<9 then 
          --do something
     when 9<myInputValue<12 then 
          --do something
end
```

how to achieve this 2 comparison as a single expression?

```
group by DATENAME(month,DATEADD(QUARTER,1, GETDATE()))
```

I need to 'group by' the datas by future quarters for expected revenues for the next years, how to achieve that too?

Comment: use `between` for that

Comment: What do you mean with a "single statement". That is a single expressions (it's not a complete _statement_ to begin with). Also: which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What if the value is 6, 9 or 12 ?

Comment: @RadimBača between is working fine. @ sarslan, 6,9,12 are quarters to check the cheques are closed within that quarters need to separate the calculations. Updated the question for another doubt.

Comment: for another question ask another question. don't add questions to other questions. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For example first condition should be rewritten as: `3 < myInputValue AND myInputValue < 6`.

Comment: I believe BETWEEN is inclusive, so those aren't equivalent.  For integers, `BETWEEN 4 AND 5` would work, but the OP hasn't said that InputValue is an integer.

Comment: between INCLUDES both parameters, so between 3 and 6 ist not equal to 3<x<6, but equal to 3<=x<=6

Comment: Thanks for remarks, wanted to give more options to the OP :)

Comment: you should then add as comment?

Answer (score 0):

because "CASE" returns the value of the FIRST true condition you can just do

```
case when myInputValue<3then 
      --do nothing
 when myInputValue<6then 
      --do something
 when myInputValue<9 then 
      --do something
 when myInputValue<12 then 
      --do something
end
```